# Is there anyway to hide the dataLabels for one of the stacked series in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

What I'm trying to do is I have a chart in which I am using multiple axes to show data. But I have stacked the 0 elements over the other elements. But when I use dataLabels the label also shows the 0 values. So is there anyway to hide those 0 values. Or any other better

Comment: fiddle link incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use formatter function and check if value is non zero: show it else don't show it.

```
 dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    rotation: 0,
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    align: 'right',
                   // format: '{point.y}', //comment it
                    x:10,
                    y: -28, // 10 pixels down from the top
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '14px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    },
      formatter: function() {
                        if (this.y != 0) {
                          return this.y;
                        } else {
                          return null;
                        }
                    }
    }

   }
```

[See working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/73oq2nzc/2/)

Comment: Tried this too. Doesn't work. Please check https://jsfiddle.net/akasheg/73oq2nzc/1/

Comment: just comment format: '{point.y} its working, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/73oq2nzc/2/

Comment: Also same thing in your fiddle, I commented format and its working https://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/73oq2nzc/3/

Comment: Also there are three texts written Values. How can I remove that. I tried so many things but nothing helped yet.

Comment: That is yAxis title, If you don't want that use  title:{text:' '} means blank